# Handling two different jobs with two different servlets but with a single submit button

Tags: java, html, database, forms, servlets

The following HTML snippet submits the *file* to *UploadHandler* which is a servlet. Then there is a caption box that also needs to be handled. I can handle the caption box in *UploadHandler* and then open the connection with the database and submit it there. But i don't want to do this . Let upload handler handle uploading of files. Then what is the alternative ? How do i submit the caption into the table ? I want to create a sense of parallelism in handling these two jobs.

```
<form method="post" action="UploadHandler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td> <strong> Browse photo to submit </strong> </td>
                <td> <input type="file" name="ImageToUpload" value="Upload Photo"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <strong> Give a Caption to this photo </strong>  </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="caption box" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr colspan="2">
                <td> <input type="submit" value="submit photo"/> </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Is there any way that when i click to submit 2 different jobs they are handled by 2 different servlets ? Creating a new thread from *UploadaHandler* doesn't seem a good idea.

After the comment by @Luiggi Mendoza :

Servlet that handles Uploading of files :

```
package projectcodes;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class UploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    String path = request.getParameter("ImageToUpload");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(!isMultipart) {
            Boolean AttemptToUploadFile = true;
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("portfolio_one.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("UploadAttempt", AttemptToUploadFile);
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItem = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItem);
            List list = null;

            try {
                list = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
            }catch(Exception exc) {
                Boolean AttemptToUploadFile = true;
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("portfolio_one.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("UploadAttempt", AttemptToUploadFile);
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }

            Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                String emailOfTheUser = null;
                FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)iterator.next();
                if(!fileItem.isFormField()) {
                    String fieldName = fileItem.getFieldName();
                    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName());
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    if(!session.isNew()) {
                        emailOfTheUser = (String)session.getAttribute("Email");
                    }
                    File file = new File("/home/non-admin/project uploads/project users/" + emailOfTheUser ,fileName);
                    fileItem.write(file);
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("portfolio_one.jsp");
                    String message = "File Uploaded successfully !";
                    request.setAttribute("SuccessMessage", message);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        Boolean AttemptToUploadFile = true;
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("portfolio_one.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("UploadAttempt", AttemptToUploadFile);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the Servlet code to submit the file?

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can if you forward from the first to the 2nd servlet, using:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/2ndServlet").forward(req, res);
```

But this is not a good idea, as it might trigger filter, the response may already by committed, etc.

What you should do is extract the functionality of the 2nd servlet in a helper class, and just invoke it, as a simple java method invocation, from the 1st servlet.

Comment: I have one more text-field to handle that makes to 3 fields. I could have more in the future. Is that ok ?

Comment: the number of fields doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

try something like in UploadHandler . it may help

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("pathToSecondServlet");
rd.forward(req, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<input type="text" name="captionBox" size="40" />
```

Then in your servlet code

```
String captionBox = request.getParameter("captionBox");
String anotherField = request.getParameter("anotherField");
//all your code
```

As @Bozho has recommended, the file upload code should be encapsulated in another class method and invoke it, maybe you will need the file upload on another servlet. Remember to [keep your code DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bozho's view . But as he suggest you can implement helper class  and implements all the opertaion(business logic) inside 1st servlet.It is quite better then RequestDispatcher. If your application operation with other button (other than submit) then it is possible.

```
Take your application with a simple diversion.
```